# How to include a Layout Fragment in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to add a layout fragment, but I keep getting the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

This is how the fragment is contained in **rev_lay_drawer_nav.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/helpAboutLL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/about_bags_bttn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="About BAGS" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/help_bttn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/rev_dr_thinner_help_top"
            android:text="Help" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is how I'm calling it:

```
mContext = context;

revLayDrawerLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from( mContext );
revLayDrawerView = revLayDrawerLayoutInflater.inflate( R.layout.rev_lay_drawer_nav, null, false );

LinearLayout helpAboutLL = (LinearLayout) revLayDrawerView.findViewById(R.id.helpAboutLL);

LinearLayout revDrawerNavViewContainer = new LinearLayout(mContext);
revDrawerNavViewContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

revDrawerNavViewContainer.addView( helpAboutLL );
```

What is the right way to go about it?

Comment: The error provides much info.The linearlayout with id helpAboutLL has already a parent View as defined by your xml. You are trying to assign a new parent to it which is wrong cause a View cannot be a child of two View parents . You could try creating an xml without the initial LinearLayout.This way helpAboutLL will have one parent. I think it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you used findViewById means that you already have a view with a parent layout.

And you can't add a view to another layout while it has that other parent view.

---

It's not clear why you need nested LinearLayouts so change your XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/helpAboutLL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/about_bags_bttn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="About BAGS" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/help_bttn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/rev_dr_thinner_help_top"
        android:text="Help" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And inflate and add just that

```
LinearLayout revDrawerNavViewContainer = new LinearLayout(mContext);
revDrawerNavViewContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

View helpAboutLL = revLayDrawerLayoutInflater.inflate( R.layout.rev_lay_drawer_nav, null, false );
revDrawerNavViewContainer.addView( helpAboutLL );
```